# Angular and CharJS - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '15' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, angular8

The folllowing error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '15' of undefined
at ChartElement.getPixelForValue (Chart.js:14599)
at ChartElement.updateElement (Chart.js:5930)
at ChartElement.addElementAndReset (Chart.js:3781)
at ChartElement.insertElements (Chart.js:4068)
at ChartElement.resyncElements (Chart.js:4059)
at ChartElement.buildOrUpdateElements (Chart.js:3806)
at Chart.update (Chart.js:9630)
```

occurs when calling `chart.update()` on a ChartJS chart in Angular 8.
This happens in specific circumstances and during debugging up to `chart.update()` the `chart` var looks ok and the sames as when the ERROR does not pop.
Any ideas what is `property '15'`and what could be causing this so I could have a lead for debugging?

EDIT:
I managed to reproduce to error with `property '0'` to `property '5'` so it is not specific to `property '15'` but still on the same function.

Comment: Could you paste some code from the file where you suspect this error is originating? It might help diagnose why this is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using chart.update() try creating the chart again.

For creating it again first you have to destroy the existing chart.

```
 update ()=>{    
   chart.destroy();
   //code for chart creation
 }
```

Comment: That fixed it thank you! Should this be a concern regarding speed? and also do you have any idea what caused the error in the first place?

Comment: May be you might have used an array and that array might not had a value at 15th index position. Will need to see your code to say for sure.